# Cant install other SDK versions

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I have the BlackBerry 7.0 SDK installed with Eclipse and that's all working. However, that means i can only develop appliations for devices running OS7 and i would like to be able to support lower operating system versions such as OS5. However, when trying to add more SDKs to my installation, the following error message appears:

```
    An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:
(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, 
operand=, action=). Unable to read repository at
 http://downloads.blackberry.com/upr/developers/Win/net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.43.jar. 
Read timed out
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says "Read timed out" which indicates that your connection timed out and Eclipse wasn't able to download the SDK.

Can you browse directly to http://downloads.blackberry.com/upr/developers/Win/net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.43.jar ?

You can download the JAR file and then load it in Eclipse.